# Load React Component after Loading MySQL Rows [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to Load data from MySQL data to render it in my component, but I noticed that my React component loads before the data loading is complete, since I'm using AJAX.

I know setTimeout is usually used to handle this situation, however, Can It be used to make an entire React Component wait until all the data is loaded, if so how.

Here is a sample of my code, I hope it helps:

**Tree.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SortableTree, { addNodeUnderParent, removeNodeAtPath,  
getFlatDataFromTree,getTreeFromFlatData, } from 'react-sortable-tree';

function loadSkillsFromServer() {
    console.log("Loading...");
    let dbData = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/skills',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //set the state with the newly loaded data so the display 
            //will update
            dbData = data;
            console.log("Loaded");
            console.log(dbData);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error('/api/skills', status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
    return dbData;
}

const initialData = loadSkillsFromServer();

export default class Tree extends Component {
      constructor(props) {...}
      render() {...}
}
```

Comment: not related to your question. but your function `loadSkillsFromServer` won't work. ajax call is asynchronous. when the`return dbData;` is execute, ajax hasn't finished running yet. for it to work, you gotta add `async: false` to your ajax call

Comment: `async: false` should be added before `url: ...`, right?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Either before or after will work

Comment: Alright, fixed it, thank you big time for pointing this out :-)

Comment: and pull `return dbData` inside the success callback

Comment: May I ask you why `loadSkillsFromServer` is outside your component?

Comment: @mersocarlin The reason I coded it the way I did is because the Component wasn't mine, It was Imported from `react-sortable-tree` by fritz-c, Initially, `const initialData` was hardcoded, and mapped into `Tree` via `treeData`, I created function `loadSkillsFromServer()` outside the Component only to change the value of `initialData` to the rows I am loading from the database, what I plan for later on is to create another `loadSkillsFromServer()` from inside Tree to directly update `treeData` with the changes that will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for more info.

```
// React.
import React from 'react'

// React Sortable Tree.
import SortableTree, {
  addNodeUnderParent,
  removeNodeAtPath,
  getFlatDataFromTree,
  getTreeFromFlatData,
} from 'react-sortable-tree'

// <Tree/>.
export default class Tree extends React.Component {

  // Constructor.
  constructor(props) {

    // Super Props.
    super(props)

    // State.
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      data: false
    }
  }

  // Render.
  render() {

    try {

      // Extract State.
      const {
        state: {
          loading,
          data
        }
      } = this

      // Loading?
      if (loading) {
        return (
          <div>Loading</div>
        )
      }

      // Data?
      if (!data) {
        return (
          <div>!Data.</div>
        )
      }

      // Complete Content.
      return (
        <div>Complete Content.</div>
      )

    } catch (error) {

      // Handle Error.
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {

    // Load Skills From Server.
    this.loadSkillsFromServer()
  }


  // Load Skills From Server.
  loadSkillsFromServer = () => {

    try {

      console.log("Loading Skills From Server ..")

      // $ Ajax Request.
      $.ajax({

        url: '/api/skills',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: () => {

          // Update State.
          return this.setState({
            loading: false,
            data
          }, () => {

            // Complete.
            console.log('Skills Loaded.')
          })

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {

            return console.error('/api/skills', status, err.toString())
        }
      })

    } catch (error) {

      // Handle Error.
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason I coded it the way I did is because the Component wasn't mine, It was Imported from react-sortable-tree by fritz-c, Initially, `const initialData` was hardcoded, and mapped into `Tree`, I created function `loadSkillsFromServer()` outside the Component only to change the value of `initialData` to the rows I am loading from the database, what I plan for later on is to create another `loadSkillsFromServer()` from inside `Tree` to directly update `treeData` with the changes that will occur.

Comment: I wouldn't call `loadSkillsFromServer` on `componentWillMount` lifecycle event. For that, please use `componentDidMount` as described in React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Answer (score 0):

Manage a React `state` to store whether the content is loaded or not.

```
this.state = {
  loading: true
}
```

Then, on the `success` callback of your AJAX call, call `setState({ loading: false })`.
Inside your component, implement conditional rendering based on `this.state.loading`; show a spinner if its true, else show the content.

Comment: The function `loadSkillsFromServer()` is outside my React class, will it still work anyways?

Comment: Place it inside `Tree`, as a class method. Don't forget to bind it like `this.loadSkillsFromServer = this.loadSkillsFromServer.bind(this)` inside constructor

Comment: You can also try calling `loadSkillsFromServer` from inside `componentDidMount`, that way you dont need to change your component